# Rails find_by and model foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, foreign-keys

I'm studying Ruby on Rails those days to improve myself as a developer so I've started to rewrite a php website of mine to play with the framework.
Basically the site is a source code aggregator, hence i have a Language model and a Source model:

```
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sources
end

class Source < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :language
end
```

Bound with the language_id foreign key in the source table.
One of the main routes of the website is:

```
get ':language_name/:source_name.html' => 'source#show'
```

So for example:

```
/ruby/discover-if-a-number-is-prime.html
```

In the SourceController I have declared the following:

```
class SourceController < ApplicationController
  def show
    language_name, source_name = params[:language_name], params[:source_name]
    @language = Language.find_by_name(language_name) || not_found
    @source = Source.find_by( name: source_name, language_id: @language.id ) || not_found
  end
end
```

Is there a clever way to perform those two queries ?
Maybe something like

```
@source = Source.find_by_name_and_language_name( source_name, language_name ) || not_found
```

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm reading Agile Web Development with Rails 3.2 too but in the meantime I'd like to experiment a little.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asked from the comments on Marek's answer, it's possible to use only 1 query using `joins`

```
@source = Source
  .joins(:language)
  .where(languages: { name: language_name })
  .where(sources: { name: source_name })
  .first
```

This will return the first `source` that matches `source_name` whose language matches `language_name`

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, I'm a performance maniac so i prefer the one-query way :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
@source = @language.sources.find_by_name(source_name)
```

or, if you want `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` to be raised if proper source doesn't exist (which eventually leads to rendering 404 page):

```
@source = @language.sources.find_by_name!(source_name)
```

Comment: noob question, isn't @language.sources fetching *every* source for that language and then filtering for the name I have ?

Comment: No, `@language.sources` returns `ActiveRecord::Relation` instance. If you call method such as `where`, `order`, or `find_by_name`, the query will be scoped appropriately. In this case, you'll get something like `SELECT sources.* FROM sources WHERE sources.language_id = {{your_language_id}} AND sources.name = {{your_source_name}}`.

Comment: @SimoneMargaritelli if you are still suspicious, you can easily check its working in rails console - it shows all SQL queries in nice form.

Comment: however this would imply two queries, one for the language and one for the source, any way to make a join in a nice way ?

Comment: @SimoneMargaritelli it would be rather difficult (and I have no idea how to make it "nice way" :). However, even Rails' `includes` used to eager loading associations use two "flat" queries instead of join, so I think single query would be perfectly enough.